# Cannot find _app.js file in nextJs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, next.js

I used "npx create-next-app" to create my NextJs project, and now encountered an interaction with _app.js to describe TransactionContext, but the problem is that it is not in my project

I would be grateful for help
[image]

Instead of the pages folder, I only have layout.tsx and page.tsx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Be careful, you created your project using the app folder. It is a new way for next.js to work, but it is in beta and for now not available for production because of some bugs.

Try to recreate your project using standard src folder. From what i remember, when you do a create-next-app, the terminal ask your preferences.

See below :

[image]

https://nextjs.org/docs/getting-started/installation

Comment: Next.js app router is stable and is ready for production use as of Next.js 13.4 - https://nextjs.org/blog/next-13-4

Comment: Nice, i'm taking this information via Reddit and some forums. And they all say that for now, even with some updates, there is still some bugs on production..